# mySql Join with 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
*
from web_user AS e
INNER JOIN web_audio AS ce ON ce.uID  = e.uID 
INNER JOIN web_videos AS c  ON c.uID = e.uID
INNER JOIN web_images AS d  ON d.uID = e.uID
WHERE e.uID = '1'
```

we have an scenario that we have 4 tables and i want to fetch records on the basis of uID from web_user table so rest of the tables will fetch records on the basis of web_user uID.
i have to get 6 records from database. but it is returning 8 that time. below is the response of my mysql query.

```
uID
uFname
uLname
uEmail
userName
uPassword
uAddress
uCity
uState
uZipcode
uPhone
uImage
userType
uGenre
website
biography
uVerifyCode
featured
activate
uStatus
uPaid
aID
uID
a_filename
a_uploadname
a_genre
a_singerName
a_approve
a_price
vID
uID
v_filename
v_uploadname
v_short_desc
v_singerName
v_approve
v_price
iID
uID
upload_file
i_approve

==========================
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
1
1
asd
muhammad_709.mp3
5
asd
0
0.00
1
1
test video
muhammad_578.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
1
1
muhammad_561.jpg
0
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
1
1
asd
muhammad_709.mp3
5
asd
0
0.00
3
1
test video
bilal_174.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
1
1
muhammad_561.jpg
0
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
1
1
asd
muhammad_709.mp3
5
asd
0
0.00
1
1
test video
muhammad_578.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
2
1
muhammad_117.jpg
0
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
1
1
asd
muhammad_709.mp3
5
asd
0
0.00
3
1
test video
bilal_174.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
2
1
muhammad_117.jpg
0
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
2
1
test file name
muhammad_976.mp3
4
test singer name
0
0.00
1
1
test video
muhammad_578.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
1
1
muhammad_561.jpg
0
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
2
1
test file name
muhammad_976.mp3
4
test singer name
0
0.00
3
1
test video
bilal_174.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
1
1
muhammad_561.jpg
0
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
2
1
test file name
muhammad_976.mp3
4
test singer name
0
0.00
1
1
test video
muhammad_578.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
2
1
muhammad_117.jpg
0
1
muhammad
mohsin
mohsin@balianti.com
mohsin
213123
test addresss
0
1
40100
333-2335-5555
fds_896_autumn-mist.jpg
1
6
NULL
NULL
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
1
1
1
1
2
1
test file name
muhammad_976.mp3
4
test singer name
0
0.00
3
1
test video
bilal_174.flv
hi test desc
test singer
0
0.00
2
1
muhammad_117.jpg
0
```

Comment: we simply want to fetch to record from other table on the basis of id 1. i am getting 8 records but it should record 6 only. without repitation

Comment: why don't you select which columns from which tables you want to show on first place

Comment: Add SELECT DISTINCT web_user.*

Comment: it could be because one or more of your table is having more than 1 record for same uID. what i mean is that web_user is having 1 record for uID ='23344', but web_audio, web_videos, web_images is having more than 1 record for same uID and this causes multiplication of records in output.

Comment: @StanislavL no lucks please. anyother solution?

Comment: @garpitmzn thank you but i have 2 2 records in each table. so why it returns 8 rows?

Comment: @RoyalBg i tried doing this as well but none of the things work for me.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT web_user.*, web_audio.*, web_images.*, web_videos.*
FROM
web_user
INNER JOIN web_videos ON web_user.uID = web_videos.userID
INNER JOIN web_audio ON web_user.uID = web_audio.userID
INNER JOIN web_images ON web_user.uID = web_images.userID
WHERE
web_user.uID = 1
 this query also returns 8 records

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT web_user.* FROM -  no need to include videa, images, audio. If user has e.g 2 images the record is included twice. Alternatively you can add GROUP BY user

Comment: @StanislavL can you write query for me please??

Comment: Create sql fiddle to and post to the question to let us have correct data and test queries

Comment: try group by web_user.uID

Comment: It is bringing back 8 records as it is bringing back every combination of the records from the web_audio, web_videos and web_images tables. 2 * 2 * 2 = 8